Where to get more ROC? I am trying to add parathread. Need 150 ROC. Can only get 100 from faucet
I am trying to follow the "reserve a parachain identifier" on the Rococo network. https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/
I installed pokadot{js} extension to my browser and created some wallets which I filled with 100 ROC from the faucet.
I can only see one of those wallets through the portal.
My issue is that the fee to reserve the identifier is about 150 ROC and I don't have enough. I had thought that maybe I could transfer my 100s all to one wallet, but I can only see one on the portal.
Does anyone have any ideas for me?
Thanks in advance

To answer my own question. I was able to add additional wallets through the plugin and populate those and then combine them!

Rococo will be deprecated soon.
I suggest you transition to Paseo.
If you need a slot or want to acquire more testnet coins, you can find support here: https://github.com/paseo-network/support.
